# sort two column by letest timestemp

Tags: phpmyadmin

I having two tables: `employee_followers` and `employee_ratings`.
In `employee_ratings` I am inserting and updating many records as per `rat_id`.

Now, I want records that have the latest time stamp in both `created_at` and `last_updated_at`. Currently I am using `order by created_at`, so it only shows `created_at` dates by the last inserted time stamp. How can I  order both `created_at` and `last_updated_at`? I tried 'order by created_at,last_updated_at' but am not getting the desired result.

This is what I have:

```
rat_id  comment     created               last_updated_at       id 
18      comment 1   2016-02-22 18:26:54   NULL                  82
9       comment 2   2016-02-22 15:48:17   2016-02-22 18:13:54   84
50      comment 3   2016-02-22 15:46:36   2016-02-22 18:18:06   86
```

This is what I want:

```
rat_id   comment    created               last_updated_at       id  
18      comment 1   2016-02-22 18:26:54   NULL                  82
50      comment 3   2016-02-22 15:46:36   2016-02-22 18:18:06   86
9       comment 2  2016-02-22 15:48:17    2016-02-22 18:13:54   84
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using phpMyAdmin, first click the header for `created_at` (or `created`, you've referred to it as both so of course use whichever is appropriate), then hold in shift while you click on the header for `last_updated_at`. Your results will look like this (note the small '1' and '2' in the column headers, in my case I've sorted in descending order of `created` and ascending `last_updated_at` to demonstrate how you can layer your sorting).

[image: Sort dialog]

...at least, that's what you wrote in the text explination -- but your demonstration of "what i want" doesn't make sense, you asked to sort by `created` but in your example it's not sorted there; the first row actually should be last (since 18 hours comes after 15).

Regardless, the way to get the multiple sort keys is by shift-clicking. If you hover over the column header, you'll see a popup with a few other options here.

Comment: hi.. issac bennetch.  as you can see i want to orderby created and last_updated_at field simultaneously  that's why i tried orderby created_at,last_updated_at field. and the output i want is listed as per time stamp  you can see that first row's created_at time is letest (18:26:54) after that second rows last_updated_at time is(18:18:06) and third ones is (18:13:54) as times temp wise i want my records to show.

Comment: I think I understand; in this case you want to sort by `last_updated_at` if it is not NULL, and if it is NULL then you want to sort by `created`. In that case, you'd first click on `last_updated_at` to sort by that, and make `created` the secondary sort field. However, from an organizational standpoint, it may be easier to set `last_updated_at` to the creation time when you first create a row (then update it when any update is performed, of course). That way, you can just sort by that one column. Anyway, swapping the sort order should accomplish your goal as I understand it